# XOR between numeric in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, integer, biginteger, unsigned

So I have two integers > 2 ^ 63 - 1 but < 2 ^ 64 -1. This is BIGINT UNSIGNED in most languages, but according to [Comparison of database column types in MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite? (Cross-Mapping)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942586/comparison-of-database-column-types-in-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite-cross-mapp), its numeric(20) in postogresql

problem is, when I try to do a postgresql xor operation between two unsigned bigints:

```
select 17418945696623429624::numeric(20) # 17418945696623429624::numeric(20);
```

=>

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: numeric # numeric
```

with any non "numeric" integer less than 2 ^ 63 -1, it works fine.

rephrase: How can I perform a XOR operation between two numbers larger than 2 ^ 63 - 1 but less than 2 ^ 64 - 1? Ex. How can I XOR 17418945696623429624 with itself in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [PostgreSQL has a bigint type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT)-- why don't you use that?

Comment: numbers like 17418945696623429624, which I need to use are larger than a bigint (2 ^ 63 - 1). I either need an unsigned bigint (which postgre doesn't support), or a numeric(20).

Comment: For XOR, it doesn't matter if you're signed or unsigned.  You could store the number as a bigint, and convert it to unsigned client side.

Comment: no i mean bigint is not big enough to store the integer I want to store. UNSIGNED BIGINT can store a larger integer than BIGINT and it is the data type im using in the MySQL version of my db.

Comment: @Shea Barton: You can convert the unsigned bigint to a signed bigint before you store it in the database.  It'll look like a negative number, but it will XOR fine.

Comment: You can use bit strings also. Both support at least 64 bit bit strings.

Answer (score 1):

According to PostgreSQL [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html):

> The bitwise operators work only on
>   integral data types, whereas the
>   others are available for all numeric
>   data types.

numeric belongs to [Arbitrary Precision Numbers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) (not [Integer Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT)), so XOR operator not works.

There is (only signed) bigint integer type, but it's only -2^63 to 2^63 - 1. Unfortunately there is no unsigned bigint datatype (i.e. 0 to 2^64 -1).

I think that it could be possible to implement such calculation using bigint datatype with some "bitwise magic".