# How to reduce PostgreSQL database size?

Tags: postgresql, types, storage, data-storage

I was planning to move from MySQL to PostgreSQL because I wanted to make use of TimescaleDB.

Everything looked good until I did a check on the storage size used by PostgreSQL (v11.2) compared to MySQL (v5.6). For exactly the same number of rows (1,440,000) and content:

- MySQL: 156 MB
- PostgreSQL: 246 MB
- PostgreSQL + TimescaleDB (partitioned/chunked data): 324 MB

The MySQL and PostgreSQL numbers are like for like (i.e. including indexes and other constraints), the PostgreSQL + TimescaleDB has overhead of adding a timestamp to the table. The table concerned looks like this:

```
create table cell(
    cell_id            serial not null
   ,ts                 timestamp not null
   ,parent_id          int references parent( parent_id )
   ,instance_id        smallint
   ,v                  float
   ,a                  float
   ,t                  float
   ,s1                 float
   ,s2                 float
   ,s3                 float
   ,s4                 float
   ,s5                 float
   ,primary key( cell_id )
);
create index ix_cell_pid on cell( parent_id );
create index ix_cell_inst on cell( instance_id );
```

Why does PostgreSQL occupy so much more storage than MySQL?
And is there some way of significantly reducing it near to the MySQL level?

Answer (score 12):

Adding a `timestamp` column should add no more than 11 MB in your case (1440000 * 8 bytes, no added padding).

Have you run **`VACUUM FULL`** in Postgres before you measured the size, for a fair comparison? I suspect table and index bloat.

Related:

- [VACUUM returning disk space to operating system](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37032/3684)
- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468)
- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23933/3684)

In MySQL the data type **`float`** is the single-precision floating point type occupying **4 bytes**.

In Postgres the same `float` is the double-precision floating point type, occupying **8 bytes** (alias: `float8` or `double precision`).

That should explain another 44 MB of the difference. To compare apples with apples, create the Postgres table with 4-byte **`real`** columns (alias `float4`). Note the difference to MySQL, where `real` is used for 8-byte floating point numbers! Unfortunate disagreements.

The MySQL manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html
The Postgres manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html

Related:

- [Comparison of database column types in MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite? (Cross-Mapping)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942586/comparison-of-database-column-types-in-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite-cross-map)

You show two **indexes**. Depending on what those are for, one multicolumn index *might* be able to replace both in Postgres - occupying just as much disk space as *one* of the two it replaces in this particular case (saving ~ 50 MB with the given specs).

```
create index ix_cell_pid on cell( parent_id, instance_id );
```

Consider:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Comment: Thx. Just did a vacuum full on the table for the PostgreSQL + TimescaleDB case. It reduced it to 297 MB, which is still quite a bit more than MySQL's 156 MB. Thanks for the references. Will read through them.

Comment: @RayCh: There is another elephant in the room: in MySQL `float` <> Postgres `float`. See added explanation.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Erwin Brandstetter's answer:

There are also the usually hidden system columns to take account of (used to implement MVCC) along with other tuple information such as hint bits (used to cache row visibility).

You can use the pageinspect extension to look at this information, e.g.:

```
create extension pageinspect;
select * from heap_page_items(get_raw_page('cell', 0));
```

See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-system-columns.html) for a description of the system columns.

Your indexes, too, will contain empty space to allow further tuples to be inserted more quickly. Look for "fillfactor" in the [CREATE INDEX docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createindex.html).

Answer (score 1):

0. connect to the database ( in psql,  type `\c your-db-name`)
1. checkout how many size each table cost. refer to: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage

```
SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation",
    pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "total_size"
  FROM pg_class C
  LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
  WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
    AND C.relkind <> 'i'
    AND nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
  ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(C.oid) DESC
  LIMIT 100;
```

2. delete or truncte the table.

```
delete ...
truncte <table_name>  cascade;
```

3. (if disk space not released) close other client which connected to postgres

Comment: worthy of mention: You have to be connected to the database before issuing the query in #1. Saved a dev.

Comment: worthy of mention: if you are considering option 2 in production, rethink, take a break for 3 days, and rethink and talk to your shrink, peers, middle managements, and then think again before execution.